# angular2 communication between components with observable

Tags: angular

I'm testing with observables. I have a component catalog-item.ts that when I click on buy I want the component basket-status.component.ts to be updated with the item I send from the catalog-item.ts. the case is that when I send the item, it arrives at the service but it does not reach the basket component, I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Any idea?

BasketWrapperService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class BasketWrapperService {
    private addItemToBasketSource = new Subject<string>();
    addItemToBasket$ = this.addItemToBasketSource.asObservable();
    addItemToBasket(item: any) {
        this.addItemToBasketSource.next(item);
    }
}
```

catalog-item.componet.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BasketWrapperService } from '../BasketWrapperService';
import { catalogModel } from '../catalogModel';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-catalog-item',
    template: '<button (click)="comprar()">Comprar producto</button>',
    styleUrls: ['./catalog-item.component.css']
    , providers: [BasketWrapperService]
})
export class CatalogItemComponent implements OnInit {
    private producto: catalogModel;
    constructor(private basketService: BasketWrapperService) { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    comprar() {
        this.producto = new catalogModel();
        this.producto.concepto = "chaqueta";
        this.producto.id = 1;
        this.producto.precio = 80.50;
        this.addToCart(this.producto);
    }

    addToCart(item: catalogModel) {
        this.basketService.addItemToBasket(item);
    }
}
```

basket-status.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { BasketWrapperService } from '../BasketWrapperService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-basket-status',
    templateUrl: './basket-status.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./basket-status.component.css'],
    providers: [BasketWrapperService]
})
export class BasketStatusComponent implements OnInit {
    subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private basketEvents: BasketWrapperService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.basketEvents.addItemToBasket$.subscribe(
            item => {
                console.log(item);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using component-level providers if you want the service instance to be shared? See e.g. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service.

Comment: Just subcribe to the subject. Subjects can be subscribed to in the same way.

Comment: @rjustin that doesn't help with two separate instances. Also, exposing the observable means it's externally read-only, which helps with encapsulation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is correct about the providers. There may be some confusion but unless you want instanced services, which is an anti-pattern, then the providers should be at the module level not in the components. Having them at a component level defeats the purpose of using services for inter component communication.

Comment: I set the providers at module level. But the problem is still.how suscribe to the subject? Any example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are using `BasketWrapperService` as Providers in each of your component. So you are creating Multiple object of `BasketWrapperService` .. Instead of creating multiple object Angular provider DI of each providers if service are provided within `Module Decorator`

```
@NgModule({
    BasketStatusComponent,
    CatalogItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    BasketWrapperService   //Provide Your service here
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

Now Your `basket-status.component.ts` **I have removed `BasketWrapperService`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { BasketWrapperService } from '../services/BasketWrapperService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-basket-status',
    template: '{{items | json}}',
})
...
...
```

Remove `BaseketWrapperService` from catalog-item.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BasketWrapperService } from '../services/BasketWrapperService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-catalog-item',
    template: '<button (click)="comprar()">Comprar producto</button>',
})
...
...
```

By doing this only 1 Object of `BasketWrapperService` is used by your Angular Aplication

Comment: Thank you so much, excellent explanation, Double H. Its works!